# Typescript does not recognize data interface type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have an array of data with types:

```
export interface Section {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  image: string,
  imageStyle?: CSSProperties,
  id?: string,
};
```

In my React component when i try to populate the array of that `Section` type data, it prevent me from build my project with the error below:

[image]

All the data in `landingSections` is type of `Section`.
It actually works when I npm run dev, only npm run build fails with that error

[image]

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, not in the code you posted.  How are you using this component?

Comment: It actually works when I npm run dev, only npm run build fails with that error

Comment: You said "All the data in landingSections is type of Section" but TypeScript doesn't seem to agree with that.  Please show how `landingSections` is declared.

Comment: I updated post with that

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code, and you said "only npm run build fails with that error", so I suspect something is wrong with your build step, not the code.  Also it's best to post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: It is saying that because `landingSections[downloadSectionIndex]` maybe `undefined` as that index may not exist. You can use not null assertion if it is guaranteed that the said index will be present everytime. And there is nothing wrong with the build step. TSC is run during build only and not on dev to maintain fast hot reloads in dev mode. You can also refactor your code to make `landingSection`s an object instead, or maybe use const assertion on the array. You can also loosen type checking for now by setting `strict: false` in `tsconfig.json`, or use an ts `ignore`/`expect-error` comment.

Comment: thanks, I make the error goes away by `const downloadSection: Section = landingSections[downloadSectionIndex] || { ...Section_obj }`

Comment: @brc-dd TypeScript will normally assume for eg `foo: string[]` that `foo[n]` is a string.  Although it can be `undefined`, TypeScript won't normally tell you this.  Is there a tsconfig option that makes it strict about that?

Comment: Here's an example with no compiler errors so show what I mean.  

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgPoC5EYBOMYA5gJSIDeAvgFB0QIYFTFlr5EmkDaAuogC8iAQG4GqDJm4deAVgAMi-uQlA

Comment: @user2740650 noUncheckedIndexedAccess

Comment: Thanks, yes, I just found noUncheckedIndexedAccess which I didn't know about.

Comment: can noUncheckedIndexedAccess  works? because checking undefined with `||` is not optimal

Comment: @KimMỹ disable it if you want. Its upto you how strict checking you want. Why not simply write this: `landingSections[downloadSectionIndex]!` . Also, using `||`/`??` may feel somewhat useless to write, it is usually the safest way. You can also remove the explicit type `Section` from your variable. It will make it `Section | undefined`, and later access its property like `foo?.title` (optional chaining).

Comment: @KimMỹ apparently you have noUncheckedIndexedAccess on, but if you want you can turn it off I guess.  Or if you are sure that the index is valid, you can assert with a "!", like `test(strings[500]!);`